# Opening a pop up window in a Vaadin Portlet

Tags: portlet, vaadin

I followed [this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.printing.html) that shows how to pop up a print window.

But, as I'm using portlets, I must get the right windows URL.
I figured out how to get the portlet URL (from the `response` object).

But, the problem is still the same : How can I get/create the Window's URL ?